# I want to create new type of simple operator class kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, types

What I want to do is save operator with number in list
and evaluate it after pushing it to list

need 2 types of operator
Add and Multiply

```
Plus(x) (x is number)
Multiply(x) (x is number)
lis = [ Plus(3), Multiply(3), Plus(4), Multiply(2) ]

When Plus Start
lis.fold(0) { total, operator -> blar..blar }
-> (((0 + 3) * 3) + 4) * 2

When Multiply Start
lis.fold(1) { total, operator -> blar..blar }
```

how to declare abstract operator

I think Plus and Multiply Operator has one infix function
something like below

```
infix fun <T>evaluate(value: T): T = this+value
or
infix fun <T>evaluate(value: T): T = this*value
```

Comment: In your example you write `lis.fold(1) ... -> (((0 + ...`. Could it be that you mean `fold(0)`, or `(((1 + ...`, respectively?

Comment: yes you are right @KarstenGabriel

Comment: What should be the result of an empty list? It has neither `Plus` nor `Multiply` as a start.

Comment: It would be 1 @KarstenGabriel

Comment: Is it important for you that `x` in `Plus` and `Multiply` can be any number? Because this is a bit problematic in Kotlin, since the generic superclass `Number` of all numbers in Kotlin does not give us enough to work with here: There is no generic plus or multiply, and there is no guarantee that a number 1 exists in just any `Number` type (e.g. you could just define a unary number class that only has 0s). It would be better to choose a specific type like `Long` or `Double`.

Comment: it can be replaced to Double!! @KarstenGabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow the distinction whether to use a 0 or a 1 depending on the first element, you could define your operation with an `identity` element:

```
open class Operation(
    val op: (Double) -> Double,
    val identity: Double,
)

class Plus(operand: Double) : Operation({ it + operand }, 0.0)
class Multiply(operand: Double) : Operation({ it * operand }, 1.0)
```

Then, the application of all elements in a list can be defined as:

```
fun List<Operation>.apply(): Double = if (isEmpty()) 1.0 else
    fold(first().identity) { total, operation -> operation.op(total) }
```

The application of all elements as in your example can then be invoked using `apply`:

```
val lis = listOf(Plus(3.0), Multiply(3.0), Plus(4.0), Multiply(2.0))
lis.apply()
```

---

If you do not like that an operator is defined and applied via its property `op` (e.g. the application of `Plus(3.0)` to a value `5.0` is done by `Plus(3.0).op(5.0)`), we can alternatively define `Operation` and the concrete subclasses in the following way:

```
abstract class Operation(val identity: Double) {
    abstract operator fun invoke(x: Double): Double
}

class Plus(private val operand: Double) : Operation(0.0) {
    override fun invoke(x: Double): Double = x + operand
}

class Multiply(private val operand: Double) : Operation(1.0) {
    override fun invoke(x: Double): Double = x * operand
}
```

Then, the `apply` function would also change:

```
fun List<Operation>.apply(): Double = if (isEmpty()) 1.0 else
    fold(first().identity) { total, operation -> operation(total) }
```

which might look a bit more intuitive.

The `invoke` operator allows us to apply the `Operation` like a function to a value, e.g. you can also write `Plus(3.0)(5.0)` to apply `_ + 3.0` to the value `5.0`.